# What does $(A-B) \cap (B-C)$ equal?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A,B,C$ are three sets then $(A-B) \cap (B-C)=$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: what have you tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x\in A-B=\{x\in A \land x\not\in B\}$$

$$x\in B-C=\{x\in B \land x\not\in C\}$$

$$x\in D\cap E =\{x\in D \land x\in E\}$$

Therefore,
$$(A-B)\cap(B-C)$$
$$=\{x\in A \land x\not\in B\}\cap \{x\in B \land x\not\in C\}$$
$$=\{x\in A \land x\not\in B \land x\in B \land x\not\in C\}$$
$$=\emptyset$$

Comment: $\not\in C$ missing a few times

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee; thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 0):

$(A-B) \cap (B-C) = \emptyset$

**Proof:**

$x \in (A-B) \implies x \notin B \implies x \notin (B-C)$

Therefore there can be no element present in both $(A-B)$ and $(B-C)$